# Problems installing a mod on my PHPBB3 forum

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I am trying to manually install a mod called "quick title edition" the install tutorial on their section is based on the style prosilver. But I am using a custom style called "Kirigami" they ask me to edit MCP_post.html and other things.. but they do not exist in the Kirigami/template/.. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kirigami template only has a few HTML templates that reside in that style template folder. If the mod was successful when installing then you only need to edit the html files in the Kirigami template folder.
This is because Kirigami template style uses prosilver.

A better explanation can be found here. https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1586785